# Find time interval where value rapidly decrease

Tags: r, time-series

I have timeseries with datetime and value, sometimes I see value is rapidly goes down. I need to find in what time did it happen.

[image]

I was thinking I need a kind of rolling window (5 mins for example) and comparing min and max Values in this window. If max/min > 2 - that means Value decrease is 50% - bingo. But how to build and analyze that windows? Or maybe there is better idea?

My example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(900)

data1 <-
    data.frame(
        datetime = seq.POSIXt(
            as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00"),
            as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 10:00:00") + 15 * 500,
            "15 sec"
        ),
        Value = sample(140000:150000, 501, replace = T)
    )

data2 <-     data.frame(
    datetime = seq.POSIXt(
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 12:05:15"),
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 12:05:15") + 15 * 100,
        "15 sec"
    ),
    Value = sample(100000:110000, 101, replace = T)
)

data3 <-     data.frame(
    datetime = seq.POSIXt(
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 12:30:30"),
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 12:30:30") + 15 * 299,
        "15 sec"
    ),
    Value = seq(100100, 130000, by = 100)
)

data4 <-     data.frame(
    datetime = seq.POSIXt(
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 13:45:30"),
        as.POSIXct("2020-12-26 13:45:30") + 15 * 2398,
        "15 sec"
    ),
    Value = seq(100, 120000, by = 50)
)

data <- do.call("rbind", list(data1, data2, data3, data4))

ggplot (data, aes(x = datetime, y = Value)) + theme_bw() + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is there a more elegant way to obtain the "rapidly decrease" but I would think that way;

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(Value2=lag(Value),diff=abs(Value2-Value)) %>%
arrange(-diff) %>%
head(2)
```

**output;**

```
  datetime             Value Value2   diff
  <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2020-12-26 13:45:30    100 130000 129900
2 2020-12-26 12:05:15 102133 142219  40086
```

**OR to obtain extreme decreases, I would calculate z scores;**

```
data %>%
mutate(Value2=lag(Value),diff=abs(Value2-Value)) %>%
mutate(z_score=(diff-mean(diff,na.rm=T))/sd(diff,na.rm=T)) %>%
filter(z_score>3)
```

**output;**

```
  datetime             Value Value2   diff z_score
  <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2020-12-26 11:15:45 140014 149687   9673    3.11
2 2020-12-26 12:05:15 102133 142219  40086   13.7 
3 2020-12-26 12:14:15 109525 100112   9413    3.02
4 2020-12-26 13:45:30    100 130000 129900   44.9
```